# Divide elements power of 2 in list and maintain list

Tags: python, list, functional-programming

I have a list of object:

```
class learn:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data

myList = []
obj1 = learn(6)
obj2 = learn(8)
obj3 = learn(14)
obj4 = learn(16)
obj5 = learn(21)

myList.append(obj1)
myList.append(obj2)
myList.append(obj3)
myList.append(obj4)
myList.append(obj5)
```

Now I would like to maintain the elements inside my list (not loosing them) and divide the power of 2 elements by 2.

I couldn't achieve that without loops, looked into filter but I kept loosing elements.

The expected output is new `list` of learn objects
`[obj(4), obj(8), obj(6), obj(14), obj(21)]`

Comment: expected output? your description is not very clear

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
Specifically, post your best attempt, the output you got, and the output you expect.

Comment: *The expected output is 4 8 6 14 21* - the power of 2 for the value `6` is `4` ???

Comment: Please clarify: you say that you want to divide certain elements by 2, but then you show a result that's a list of integers, instead a of a list of **learn** objects.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I don't he cares how the output list is organized...
4 and 8 stand for 16 and 8 he appeneded. That is my guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myList1 incase you want a list of learn Obj, and myList2 incase you want a list of ints

```
def is_power2(num):
    return num != 0 and ((num & (num - 1)) == 0)

List1 = list(filter(lambda  x: is_power2(x._data), myList))
List2 = list(filter(lambda x: not is_power2(x._data), myList))
List1 = [learn(o._data/2) for o in List1]
myList1 = List1 + List2
myList2 = [o._data for o in List1]
```